# Android view Inflate exception?

Tags: android, xml

I have a small bit of xml code that inflates a views as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:elektromotus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/eu.elektromotus"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<eu.elektromotus.widget.DashboardView
    android:id="@+id/dashboardView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/dashboard_back"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/error_notifier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/notifier_bg"
    android:contentDescription="@string/msg_error_notifier"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_alert"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</merge>
```

When I run my application i get the following errors in my log:

```
android.view.inflateException: Binary XML line #8: Error inflating class eu.elektromotus.widget.DashBoardView
```

Did i do something wrong with the implementation? Or could my problem be elsewhere?

Comment: Does the constructor for your DashboardView class get invoked at runtime?

Comment: How do you mean? Would you like to see the dashBoard view class? Sorry bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be your custom `DashboardView` class constructor is not calling the right `super constructor` View. When you refer to a custom view in `XML`, the class constructor should pass `AttributeSet` along with the context like this.

```
public class DashboardView extends View {
  public DashboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
    }
 }
```

*Also , make sure the custom class package name in XML is correct*